# How to replace substring of a datatable field with another string in c#

Tags: c#, replace, datatable

I have a datatable as [image]

I want to replace all ESM of estm_suffix values with the a string which will come based on cust_Id.
I am retrieving the string as

```
       for (int i=0; i < dtRefNos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            intCustId = int.Parse(dtRefNos.Rows[i]["cust_Id"].ToString());
            dsCustmr = custDCCls.FillCustDataSet(intCustId);
            string shrtName = dsCustmr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cust_Sname"].ToString();
        }
```

No w I want to replace only ESM substring from estm_suffix with shrtName as ESM/00001/12-13 to shrtName/00001/12-13 and have to return the datatable. Please anybody help me.

Comment: Do you want the `shrtName` to be replaced for each row respectively ? in data table `dtRefNos` ? or do you want to replace all the rows with a single value of `shrtName` ?

Comment: each row with respective shrtNames sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your comment

> each row with respective shrtNames

and

> I dont want to replace all the value of estm_sufffix. I want to
>   replace only ESM substring from ESM/00001/12-13

You can simply put one more line in your `for` loop to replace `estm_suffix` values with `shrtName` using [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx), like:

```
for (int i=0; i < dtRefNos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            intCustId = int.Parse(dtRefNos.Rows[i]["cust_Id"].ToString());
            dsCustmr = custDCCls.FillCustDataSet(intCustId);
            string shrtName = dsCustmr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cust_Sname"].ToString();
            //New Line
            dtRefNos.Rows[i]["estm_suffix"] = dtRefNos.Rows[i].Field<string>("estm_suffix")
                                          .Replace("ESM", shrtName);
        }
```

Comment: Sir I dont want to replace all the value of estm_sufffix. I want to replace only ESM substring from ESM/00001/12-13.

Comment: you mean..shoul I pass each row to a DataRow variable?  as drRefNos

Comment: @NareshJadapalli, no, just run the code, and your `dtRefNos` will be updated after the loop has finished execution

Comment: drRefNos does not exists sir.. That's why I have asked you.

Comment: @NareshJadapalli, ohh my bad, thats a typo, its `dtRefNos.Rows[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use Regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

for (int i=0; i < dtRefNos.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    intCustId = int.Parse(dtRefNos.Rows[i]["cust_Id"].ToString());
    dsCustmr = custDCCls.FillCustDataSet(intCustId);
    string shrtName = dsCustmr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cust_Sname"].ToString();
    string str = dtRefNos.Rows[i]["estm_suffix"].toString();
    str = Regex.Replace(str, "ESM", dtRefNos.Rows[i]["shrtName"].toString());
    dtRefNos.Rows[i]["estm_suffix"] = str;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `Regex.Replace` since you are simply doing string.Replace ?